# Kompose up username and password authentication

Tags: kubernetes, authorization, k3s, kompose

I'm experimenting with using kompose on `k3s` to turn the compose file into a K8s file, but when I type `kompose up`, it asks me to enter a `username and password`, but I don't know what to write.

The specific output is as follows

```
# kompose up
INFO We are going to create Kubernetes Deployments, Services and PersistentVolumeClaims for your Dockerized application. If you need different kind of resources, use the 'kompose convert' and 'kubectl create -f' commands instead. 
 
Please enter Username: test
Please enter Password: test
FATA Error while deploying application: Get https://127.0.0.1:6443/api: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

However, the `kompose convert` command was successfully executed

I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to solve it?

> The kompose version is `1.21.0 (992df58d8)`, and install it by 'curl and chmod'
>
> The k3s version is `v1.17.3+k3s1 (5b17a175)`, and install it by 'install.sh script'
>
> OS is `Ubuntu18.04.3 TLS`

Comment: What `kompose` version did you install? How did you configure your k3s cluster? Did you create any certs? What is your OS?

Comment: @PjoterS K3s is installed using the `install.sh` script and I haven't set up the k3s node yet, just a master node. Kompose is version `1.21.0` and is installed using `curl and chmod`. I didn't create any `certs`, only script installation was used. The `lsb_release -a` command shows that the OS is `ubuntu18.04.3 TLS`.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have found my problem, because I use k3s the install.sh scripts installed by default, it will k8s configuration file stored in the `/etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml` instead of k8s `~/.Kube/config`.

This caused kompose up to fail to obtain certs.

You can use the `/etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml` copied to `~/.Kube/config`.

```
cp /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml ~/.kube/config
```

Then `kompose up` executes successfully.

Comment: The same "lack of credentials" issue can happen to users who aren't using k3s/rancher/etc. because the docker socket requires root to access it, but `kubectl` does not. Therefore, you will need to run `sudo kompose`. And for that to work, you must give the root user a copy of the config. `sudo mkdir -p /root/.kube; sudo cp ~/.kube/config /root/.kube/`

Answer (score 0):

The answer that the OP gave is for a different issue than the `certificate signed by unknown authority` that they posted. The certificate issue is almost certainly caused by a self signed cert. For that, you have to get your workstation's OS to accept the cert. For Linux, I use:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect 127.0.0.1:6443 2>/dev/null </dev/null | \
  sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' | \
  sudo tee /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/k8s.crt
sudo update-ca-certificates
sudo systemctl restart docker
```